# Access prohibit the entry two spaces in field

Tags: ms-access

In MS Access, how can I prohibit the entry of two spaces in the field in the table? Is it possible directly in the table or by using a form?

Example: John__Smith

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like something that you need to handle on a data entry form.

You can use the AfterUpdate event for the control and write code to check for 2 spaces in a row, and then remove one.

Comment: Yes, don't bother the user with trivials. Just call `Replace(Me!YourField.Value, "  ", " ")` in the AfterUpdate event.

Answer (score 2):

You can enforce that requirement in your table's design with a *Validation Rule* for the field:

[image: field Validation Rule]

Note I used `ALike` which tells the db engine to treat `%` as a wildcard to match zero or more of any characters.  If you prefer `Like`, use this for the *Validation Rule* property: `Not Like '*  *'`